# Batch adding attribute to attribute sets

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento installation with around 60 attribute sets.  I need to add a new attribute to each of the attribute sets.  There doesn't seem to anyway of doing this in the admin control panel.

I am sure I can work it out by manually entering the correct fields into the database, but is there a way of doing this through the API or through the Import / Export profiles?

Any suggestions would be gladly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the documentation for import and export profiles is so thin for magento you are better off going direct to the DB.

As you say you're capable i'm sure you've seen the tables you need are the eav_* tables for you chars and int etc etc.

Also the API has weird quirks, i unintentionally sent 1k+ emails to imported customers, saying they had subscribed to the magento demo store, doh! who thought that was a good feature.

Comment: Oh dear!  Thanks for the heads up on the API - I haven't really used it yet. I think the documentation for the development side of Magento is thin, and really lets it down.

Comment: Yes understandably thin for an open source project, as always docs are the least favorite thing for programmers.

Comment: I ended up changing the database direct (I needed to this done ASAP).  I have posted how I did this here: http://www.bytesite.co.uk/magento-batch-adding-attributes-to-attribute-sets. Cheers for your help.